# How do I reference an assembly that is in the GAC?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, gac

H Since the .NET tab in the "Add Reference ..." dialog does not show the assemblies form the GAC what is the common best practise to add a reference to an assembly that was installed in GAC to my visual studio project?

Comment: Are you sure your assembly isn't showing up in the '.NET' tab on the add-references dialog?

Comment: You may need to restart VS after installing the assemblies in the GAC, as new assemblies may not show in the list.

Comment: Yes it is a commonly fallacy to think the "Add reference" dialog retrieves its assembly list form the GAC. This is not true, it gets it from some registry keys and special folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article mentions the registry keys which you can modify to directly show the assemblies from GAC  http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2003/12/16/43841.aspx

[How can I reference a dll in the GAC from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444655/how-can-i-reference-a-dll-in-the-gac-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

"Add Reference..." dialog modifies your project file (for example .csproj for C#). It is simple msbuild file. To add reference to your project you should modify node: Reference

```
<Reference Include="System.Data.Services">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using the VS tooling/GUI?