# Project don't see library in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, gac, .net-4.6

I have console app, and lib project in solution.
After I built solution, I register lib project [dll] to GAC(and checked that it is there) and remove that dll from folder. But my console application cannot run because it cannot find lib dll.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reference a dll in the GAC from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444655/how-can-i-reference-a-dll-in-the-gac-from-visual-studio)

Comment: What If I want to add this assembly to GAC on client machine. And when I develop I need get it from solution?